# How to get a list of all pending security updates?

Tags: apt, updates

I need to **list** (not count or install) all pending security updates on an Ubuntu 14.04 system.  I've read the post [How to create a list of of only security updates with apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/555931/how-to-create-a-list-of-of-only-security-updates-with-apt-get) and its accepted answer (`apt-show-versions | grep upgradeable | grep security`) does indeed give me a list.

However, that command lists 62 pending security updates.  `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check` tells me that I have 75 pending security updates, but doesn't seem to have a way to list them.  How can I reconcile these two numbers?  Is one of the two commands doing something other than what I want?

Answer (score 19):

- `apt list --upgradable` list all updates available
- `apt list --upgradable | grep "\-security"` lists all updates that are security.
- `apt list --upgradable 2>/dev/null | grep "\-security" | wc -l` counts number of security updates available. and redirects the stderr like "`WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.`" to null

Comment: This is not entirely correct. On a system of ours, it lists 7 packages, while `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check` lists 12 security updates. Too bad it cannot list them.

Comment: Works for me in a pinch. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: This only lists packages offered for `upgrade`, not packages offered for `dist-upgrade`.  (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/441921/why-does-usr-lib-update-notifier-apt-check-not-agree-with-apt-get-upgrade) `unattended-upgrades` only upgrades the former (by default), while `apt-check` counts the latter.

Answer (score 15):

If you are just looking to do this quickly once, instead of creating a separate repository and scripting up some automation and all that. Great if you aren't supposed to be making changes while auditing a system or whatever.

These two commands will spit out the list. Pipe to wc -l to see how many are behind. ;-)

```
grep security /etc/apt/sources.list > /tmp/security.list
sudo apt-get upgrade -oDir::Etc::Sourcelist=/tmp/security.list -oDir::Etc::SourceParts=/some/valid/dir/false -s
```

Still valid for older distros or if you have update repos off, but security on:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade -s | grep ^Inst | grep -i security
```

Comment: why do you write ”_Still valid for older distros or if you have update repos off, but security on_“? if the piped solution does not work, maybe add the `-V` (`-verbose-versions`) option?

Comment: @myrdd Because the first uses features that weren't available on distros that were going out of style back in 2016. Might not be a thing anymore.

Comment: so the latter solution should always work, no?

Comment: @myrdd As long as the format of the output doesn't change in a newer version. The first is better because it isn't dependent upon format of output.

Answer (score 7):

there must be a way to request how many packages are updatable and how many security updates ***right now***, but if you settle for asking it once a day you can simply read the file **/var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available**, which seems to be updated daily by the script **/etc/cron.daily/update-notifier-common** which belongs to the package **update-notifier-common**

Example:

```
$ sudo cat /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available

355 packages can be updated.
1 update is a security update.
```

Tested in:

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Regards,

/Ángel

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo apt-get -s --no-download dist-upgrade -V | grep "^Inst.*security.*$" | cut -d " " -f 2
```

With some help from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/449378/44225)

Comment: Or if you want to avoid `sudo`: `apt-get -s dist-upgrade -V | awk '/^Inst.*security/ {print $2}'`

Answer (score 4):

The other answers given here do not all list the same security upgrades.

Ubuntu has two standard policies for upgrading packages: `apt-get upgrade` is more conservative than `apt-get dist-upgrade`. [The latter will generally upgrade more packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194651/why-use-apt-get-upgrade-instead-of-apt-get-dist-upgrade#answer-226213), and it may contain security upgrades that the former ignores.

The notification shown (by default) upon login is a cached copy of the output of `apt-check`:

```
$ /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable
92 packages can be updated.
3 updates are security updates.
```

These numbers [count packages that will be upgraded by `apt-get dist-upgrade`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441921/why-does-usr-lib-update-notifier-apt-check-not-agree-with-apt-get-upgrade#answer-441934); [you can list these security upgrades as follows](http://#answer-1110400):

```
sudo apt-get --no-download -s dist-upgrade -V | awk '/^Inst.*security/ {print $2}'
```

or

```
apt-get -s dist-upgrade -V | awk '/^Inst.*security/ {print $2}'
```

To see just the security upgrades in an `apt-get upgrade`, do

```
apt-get -s upgrade -V | awk '/^Inst.*security/ {print $2}'
```

or

```
apt list --upgradable
```

By default, `unattended-upgrades` only runs an `upgrade`, not `dist-upgrade`.

This explains why `unattended-upgrades`, even when configured to automatically install security upgrades, doesn't always install all security upgrades reported by `apt-check`.

All of these tools use the local package index - so to check the status on the Ubuntu mirror your host is using, first update it with  `sudo apt update`.

[A mirror can be out of date in principle](https://serverfault.com/questions/1051598/how-do-i-reliably-determine-on-ubuntu-when-the-latest-version-of-a-package-was-m), so if you want to check at the source, you need to check on Launchpad - at least for packages distributed by Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```sh
sudo unattended-upgrade --dry-run -d 2> /dev/null | awk '/Checking/ { print $2 }'
```

Comment: Shows all available updates, but doesnt limit to security-updates if i'm not mistaken. Still helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt list --upgradable |grep "/$(lsb_release -cs)-security"
```

This lists all available updates which come via the security repository.

Comment: apt is for interactive use. You get a warning when used in a script. Use `apt-get` instead.

Comment: This lists `upgrade`s, not `dist-upgrade`s.

Answer (score 0):

Mystery solved: `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check` counts "real" packages whereas `apt list --upgradable` counts virtual packages. Example:

```
8 updates can be installed immediately.
8 of these updates are security updates.

apt list --upgradable # only 3 lines
linux-generic/focal-updates,focal-security 5.4.0.56.59 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.4.0.53.56]
linux-headers-generic/focal-updates,focal-security 5.4.0.56.59 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.4.0.53.56]
linux-image-generic/focal-updates,focal-security 5.4.0.56.59 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.4.0.53.56]

apt upgrade
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-5.4.0-56 linux-headers-5.4.0-56-generic linux-image-5.4.0-56-generic
  linux-modules-5.4.0-56-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-56-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
3 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: I don't think this is true. Rather, `apt list` only looks at `upgrade`s, while `apt-check` looks at `dist-upgrade`s. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/441921/why-does-usr-lib-update-notifier-apt-check-not-agree-with-apt-get-upgrade