# How are package updates defined as security updates?

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, mirrors, unattended-upgrades

I've created and published a mirror of the Ubuntu repositories for Xenial using aptly. This includes `xenial` and `xenial-updates` downloaded from my country specific Ubuntu mirror. I've taken `xenial-security` from `http://security.ubuntu.com`. I can use all `apt` or `apt-get` update and upgrade commands normally with this mirror to manually upgrade systems.

My issue is that `unattended-upgrades` with security only updates configured will not register any packages as available to upgrade. Likewise after using `apt update`, the motd message on login will say something like:

```
261 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.
```

If I switch back to the default repositories and run the same command, motd changes to:

```
261 packages can be updated.
176 updates are security updates.
```

Running `unattended-upgrade --dry-run -d` has similar results, plenty of security updates if I use the default mirrors, but none from my local mirror.

Evidently I'm losing whatever marks the packages as security updates in my mirroring process.

**How does apt determine that a package update is a security update once the package list has been updated? What do I have to do to accurately mirror this?**

Comment: Nothing 'marks' a security update, they simply come from a specific pocket (-security). Passing packages through a local repo (as opposed to a caching proxy) should indeed confuse the motd scripts.

Comment: @user535733 I've found out that it's due to aptly changing the 'Origin:' field in the InRelease file to match the publishing endpoint. The scripts responsible for updating motd and for determining whether updates are security updates will only accept the origin being 'Ubuntu'. Once I modified the Inrelease file on my mirror the xenial-security pocket was recognised as being a valid source for security updates. I think that belongs in a new question and answer though. It was interesting to note that the motd message is updated immediately after any `apt update` command though.

Answer (score 1):

"Security Updates" come from the -security repository. Only the [Ubuntu Security Team](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam) has permission to upload to that pocket. Apt does not "determine" anything.

Example: Security updates in Xenial are packaged by the Ubuntu Security Team and distributed in the xenial-security pocket.

For your specific case:

1) Ensure that you really have a security repo enabled in sources.list.

2) Don't trust motd's numbers - motd is a a handy reminder feature, but those numbers update only once per day...and you don't know when.

3) Try [one of these methods](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774805/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-pending-security-updates) to accurately see if uninstalled security updates are in the -security pocket for your release of Ubuntu.

4) Unattended Upgrades can be really sneaky about upgrades (that's good). Check a week of the U-U history in /var/log/unattended-upgrades to be certain that U-U is not installing security upgrades. If so, time to double-check your sources (see #1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this doesn't match what I'm seeing. Motd is updated immediately after `apt update`. I have a mirror with the `xenial-security` pocket published containing the contents of the official `-security` pocket. I'm pretty up to speed with the unattended-upgrades log, definitely nothing in there. Also running the `unattended upgrade --dry-run -d` command gives much more verbose output, showing the exact same package version being checked for both sources, but the local repo version not needing to be updated as a security concern.