# How do I PREVIEW ONLY outstanding security updates?

Tags: security

I have an AWS instance running 4.4.0-1037-aws #40-Ubuntu.
When I login in get:

109 packages can be updated.
89 updates are security updates.

How do I preview which these are?
and
How do I install them?

Regards

Tariq

Comment: What do you mean by "preview?" Are you asking for a list of the upgradable packages in the -security pocket? Or are you asking for something else? Ubuntu is not designed to pick-and-choose among upgrades - doing so can cause all kinds of problems for non-experts. Generally, we recommend Unattended Upgrades to most users, which avoids precisely this question.

Comment: If you simply want a list of the -security upgrades, see https://askubuntu.com/a/1088549/19626

Answer (score 0):

To **preview** (edited the answer linked in user535733 comment: no sudo needed, and shouldn't escape `$`):

`apt list --upgradable | grep "$(lsb_release -cs)-security"`

To **install**:

`sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: Thanks, how does one just upgrade security updates?

Comment: As you can tell from the man page, apt upgrade is all or nothing (for good reasons). It doesn't allow you to cherry pick which package to upgrade. However, there is a way to upgrade selectively. But it's too much to fit into comments comfortably. Why don't you ask a new question "How do I selectively upgrade packages?" and I will answer it there.

Comment: And before you go, accept this answer since I believe it already answered your original question, and ideally also upvote it, and more ideally also get your friends to upvote it ;) Right now I am in this ridiculous situation where I can't even leave a comment, and people think I am just like other newbies who come and go taking what they want leaving nothing in return, and some may even take one step further to assume I don't know what I am talking about -- making it much less fun to contribute here.