# apt-check vs apt update different result

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, updates

On my Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS server i run my script with cron hourly. It's generate a text file. This file processed by conky on my desktop PC.
In my script i use apt-check to know is there any update and if is how many is security.
My problem is: apt-check and apt update totally different result. for example right now apt-check:

```
$(/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check)
17;1
```

same numbers which in motd message

however

```
apt update
apt upgrade
0 upgraded, 0 newly, 0 remove
```

why different output?
how can i run apt to give me 2 numbers only like 17;1?

Comment: `apt-check` queries the local package cache. `apt update` queries the mirrors. If they have the same result, that's a coincidence of good timing since the mirrors get new updates constantly. For a list of security updates, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/774805/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-pending-security-updates; converting the list to a number (using `wc`) is left as an exercise for the student.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
my solution is:
upgradable packages:
`apt list --upgradable 2>&1 | wc -l | awk '{print $0-4}'`
security upgrades:
`apt list --upgradable 2>&1 | grep "\-security" | wc -l`